# VBA code to format an entire column up one row

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a VBA program that will run in the background of my excel file. This VBA program will read fields in from a folder of text files. I have gotten the fields I need read in, I am just having trouble with the formatting. Every value that is read out is put on the next line in the excel file, but it puts it in the correct row, so I need to figure out how to move a whole column up one row once everything is read in. Below I have added my entire program, which was the easiest to see when entering it under the java header(it is VBA code). I have left out my cLines class where my values get stored. The part in the program that writes to the worksheet is where I believe that we will have to insert the formatting.

```
    'Main Module

Option Explicit
'NOTE:  Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub FindInFile()
    Dim sBaseFolder As String, sFindText As String, sFindTracNum As String, sFindTrailNum As String, sFindRemarks As String
    Dim FD As FileDialog
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, FIs As Files, FI As File, FO As Folder
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Dim colL As Collection, TracNum As Collection, TrailNum As Collection, Remarks As Collection, cL As cLines
    Dim S As String, strPath As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim R As Range
    Dim wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range, vRes() As Variant

'Set results worksheet and range
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

sFindText = "Driver Name:"
sFindTracNum = "Tractor #:"
sFindTrailNum = "Trailer #:"
sFindRemarks = "Remarks:"

'Specify the folder
strPath = "C:\test\Excel Test"



'Get the Text files in the folder
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FO = FSO.GetFolder(strPath)
Set FIs = FO.Files


'Collect the information
Set colL = New Collection
Set TracNum = New Collection
Set TrailNum = New Collection
Set Remarks = New Collection

For Each FI In FIs
With FI
    If .Name Like "*.txt" Then
        I = 0
        Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(strPath & "\" & .Name, ForReading)
        Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream
            S = TS.ReadLine
            I = I + 1
            Set cL = New cLines

            If InStr(1, S, sFindText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                With cL
                    .LineText = S
                End With

                colL.Add cL

            ElseIf InStr(1, S, sFindTrailNum, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                With cL
                    .TrailNum = S
                End With


                colL.Add cL

            End If
        Loop
    End If
End With
Next FI

'Write the collection to a VBA array
ReDim vRes(0 To colL.Count, 1 To 6)

'Column Headers

vRes(0, 1) = "Driver Name"
vRes(0, 2) = "Tractor#"
vRes(0, 3) = "Trailer#"
vRes(0, 4) = "Remarks"
vRes(0, 5) = "Next" & vbLf & "Plan"
vRes(0, 6) = "Status" & vbLf & "of" & vbLf & "Repairs"


For I = 1 To colL.Count
With colL(I)
    vRes(I, 1) = .LineText
    vRes(I, 2) = .TracNum
    vRes(I, 3) = .TrailNum
    vRes(I, 4) = .Remarks
End With
Next I

'Write to the worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With .Columns(3)
        '.EntireRow.Cut
        '.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    End With
    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 45
    With .EntireRow
        .WrapText = True
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .AutoFit
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'Remove the FindWord
    For Each R In rRes.Offset(1).Resize(rRes.Rows.Count - 1).Columns(1).Cells
        I = 1
        Do
            I = InStr(I, R.Text, sFindText, vbTextCompare)
            With R.Characters(I, Len(sFindText))
                .Delete

            End With
            I = InStr(I + 1, R.Text, sFindText, vbTextCompare)


        Loop Until I = 0
    Next R

    For Each R In rRes.Offset(1).Resize(rRes.Rows.Count - 1).Columns(3).Cells
        I = 1
        Do
            I = InStr(I, R.Text, sFindTrailNum, vbTextCompare)
            With R.Characters(I, Len(sFindTrailNum))
                .Delete

            End With
            I = InStr(I + 1, R.Text, sFindTrailNum, vbTextCompare)


        Loop Until I = 0
    Next R

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub'
```

Comment: Is your question, "how to delete blank cells at the top of a column?"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the updated VBA code:

```js
Option Explicit


'Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Call FindInFile
'End Sub

'NOTE:  Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub FindInFile()

 '   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01"), "FindInFile"
    
    Dim sBaseFolder As String, sFindText As String, sFindTracNum As String
    Dim sFindTrailNum As String, sFindRemarks As String, sFindDefect As String
    Dim FD As FileDialog
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, FIs As Files, FI As File, FO As Folder
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Dim colL As Collection, TracNum As Collection, TrailNum As Collection
    Dim Remarks As Collection, Defect As Collection, cL As cLines
    Dim S As String, C As String, strPath As String
    Dim I As Long, T As Long, G As Long, H As Long
    Dim R As Range
    Dim wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range, vRes() As Variant
    
'Set results worksheet and range
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)
   
'Set text you will search for in files
sFindText = "Driver Name:"
sFindTracNum = "Tractor #:"
sFindTrailNum = "Trailer #:"
sFindRemarks = "Remarks:"
sFindDefect = "Defect Found?: No"

'Specify the folder
strPath = "C:\test\Excel Test"



'Get the Text files in the folder
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FO = FSO.GetFolder(strPath)
Set FIs = FO.Files


'Collect the information
Set colL = New Collection
Set TracNum = New Collection
Set TrailNum = New Collection
Set Remarks = New Collection
Set Defect = New Collection

'Get each field out of the text files
For Each FI In FIs
With FI
    If .Name Like "*.txt" Then
        I = 0
        Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(strPath & "\" & .Name, ForReading)
        Do Until TS.AtEndOfStream
            S = TS.ReadLine
            I = I + 1
            Set cL = New cLines
            
            If InStr(1, S, sFindDefect, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                                
                                
                'If (S = "Defect Found?: Yes") Then
                'End If
            End If
            If InStr(1, S, sFindText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                
                With cL
                    .LineText = S
                End With

                colL.Add cL
                
            ElseIf InStr(1, S, sFindTrailNum, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                
                With cL
                    .TrailNum = S
                End With

                TrailNum.Add cL
                       
            ElseIf InStr(1, S, sFindRemarks, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                
                With cL
                    .Remarks = S
                End With

                Remarks.Add cL
                                       

            End If
        Loop
    End If
End With
Next FI

'Write the collection to a VBA array
ReDim vRes(0 To colL.Count, 1 To 5)

'Column Headers

vRes(0, 1) = "Driver Name"
vRes(0, 2) = "Tractor#"
vRes(0, 3) = "Trailer#"
vRes(0, 4) = "Remarks"
vRes(0, 5) = "Defect?"
'vRes(0, 6) = "Status" & vbLf & "of" & vbLf & "Repairs"

'Get all of the information on the correct line
For I = 1 To colL.Count
With colL(I)
    vRes(I, 1) = .LineText
End With
Next I

For T = 1 To TrailNum.Count
With TrailNum(T)
    vRes(T, 3) = .TrailNum
End With
Next T

For G = 1 To Remarks.Count
With Remarks(G)
    vRes(G, 4) = .Remarks
End With
Next G

For H = 1 To Defect.Count
With Defect(H)
    vRes(H, 5) = .Defect
End With
Next H


'Write to the worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .RowHeight = 36
    End With
    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 45
    With .EntireRow
        .WrapText = True
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        '.AutoFit
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit

    'Remove the word that is found
    For Each R In rRes.Offset(1).Resize(rRes.Rows.Count - 1).Columns(1).Cells
        I = 1
        Do
            I = InStr(I, R.Text, sFindText, vbTextCompare)
            With R.Characters(I, Len(sFindText))
                .Delete
            End With
            I = InStr(I + 1, R.Text, sFindText, vbTextCompare)
            
        Loop Until I = 0
    Next R
    
    For Each R In rRes.Offset(1).Resize(rRes.Rows.Count - 1).Columns(3).Cells
        I = 1
        Do
            I = InStr(I, R.Text, sFindTrailNum, vbTextCompare)
            With R.Characters(I, Len(sFindTrailNum))
                .Delete
            End With
            I = InStr(I + 1, R.Text, sFindTrailNum, vbTextCompare)
            
        Loop Until I = 0
    Next R
    
        For Each R In rRes.Offset(1).Resize(rRes.Rows.Count - 1).Columns(4).Cells
        I = 1
        Do
            I = InStr(I, R.Text, sFindRemarks, vbTextCompare)
            With R.Characters(I, Len(sFindRemarks))
                .Delete
            End With
            I = InStr(I + 1, R.Text, sFindRemarks, vbTextCompare)
            
        Loop Until I = 0
    Next R

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```